# Magento2 - In eav_attribute_option_swatch table New option value not inserting

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I have `400+` visualswatch options, whenever I add new one, It will insert in `eav_attribute_option_value` but the Admin value which is supposed to be inserted in `eav_attribute_option_swatch` is not being inserted, instead. 
It will just update the last option before the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved issue, set value '0' in sort_order column in eav_attribute_option table.
There was duplicate sort order value in table.

```
run sql query:
UPDATE `eav_attribute_option` SET `sort_order`=0 WHERE `attribute_id` = 93;
```